# Webpack External dependencies and jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, jestjs, enzyme

I'm using a webpack external dependency

```
// wepack.config.dev.js
externals: {
    amdRequire: 'require'
}

// component.js

import amdRequire from 'amdRequire'

//component.test.js

shallow(<component/>
/*Basic test*/
```

I get this error

```
Cannot find module 'amdRequire' from 'component.js'
    at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:179:17)
```

I been trying a way to mock this external dependencies. 
I tried using the below setup without much luck

1. Jest-webpack-resolver
2. create a file in *mock* folder
3. adding global.amdRequire in a file and adding the file in package.json -> jest -> setupFiles